# ensure same N across nested multinomial models

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm running a set of nested models and need to ensure all models have the same N and use the same observations.

In Stata, I could run the model with the smallest N, generate a flag of the observations used in the model using e(sample) command, and then use that as a filter when I run the regression. Does anyone know who to do this in R? Using `tidy()` or `augment()` doesn't seem to work for multinomial models using the `multinom`  package.

Thanks for the help. Sample code using `palmerpenguins` package:

```
install.packages("palmerpenguins")
library(palmerpenguins)

head(penguins)
View(penguins)

# models 
multinom_islands <- list(
  "model 1"  = nnet::multinom(island ~ bill_length_mm + bill_depth_mm,
                              data = penguins, trace = FALSE, na.action = "na.exclude"),
  "model 2"  = nnet::multinom(island ~ bill_length_mm + bill_depth_mm + sex + year, 
                              data = penguins, trace = FALSE, na.action = "na.exclude"))


# tables 
modelsummary(multinom_islands, group = y.level + term ~ model, 
             exponentiate = TRUE, 
             stars = c("*"=.05, "**"=.01, "***"=0.001), 
             title = "Nested multinomial regression models predicting island",
             output = "markdown")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you describe is Stata would not be guaranteed to work unless the variables in the “small” model are a subset of the variables in the “large” model.

One way to be sure you get the expected results is to begin by creating a new dataset with all the variables from all models. Then, we use the `na.omit` function to eliminate all missing data. Finally, we estimate the models. This does not guarantee the largest possible sample size, but it guarantees that all models will have the same number of observations:

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(nnet)

variables <- c("island", "bill_length_mm", "bill_depth_mm", "sex", "year")
dat <- penguins[, variables]
dat <- na.omit(dat)

mod <- list(
  multinom(island ~ bill_length_mm + bill_depth_mm,
           data = dat, trace = FALSE),
  multinom(island ~ bill_length_mm + bill_depth_mm + sex + year,
           data = dat, trace = FALSE))

modelsummary(mod, group = y.level + term ~ model, output = "markdown")
```

|  |  | Model 1 | Model 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dream | (Intercept) | -16.087 | 0.008 |
|  |  | (2.340) | (0.000) |
|  | bill_length_mm | 0.008 | 0.096 |
|  |  | (0.027) | (0.032) |
|  | bill_depth_mm | 0.899 | 1.219 |
|  |  | (0.104) | (0.116) |
|  | sexmale |  | -2.202 |
|  |  |  | (0.286) |
|  | year |  | -0.012 |
|  |  |  | (0.001) |
| Torgersen | (Intercept) | -9.346 | -0.006 |
|  |  | (3.297) | (0.000) |
|  | bill_length_mm | -0.209 | -0.149 |
|  |  | (0.047) | (0.049) |
|  | bill_depth_mm | 0.966 | 1.133 |
|  |  | (0.157) | (0.155) |
|  | sexmale |  | -1.302 |
|  |  |  | (0.171) |
|  | year |  | -0.007 |
|  |  |  | (0.002) |
|  | Num.Obs. | 333 | 333 |
|  | AIC | 482.9 | 458.4 |
|  | edf | 6.000 | 10.000 |

Comment: Thanks, @Vincent. Yea, the Stata process works by ensuring the "smaller" models are a subset of the "larger" models. Stata identifies the actual observations. I feel like there's gotta be an easy way to do that in R too. But your solution worked perfectly. Thanks again.